# Razorpay angular 9 integration - Modal Close - Routing and reload reopens Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, razorpay

We have implemented razor-pay payment gateway using angular 9.

Razorpay payment gateway lib is in vanilla javascript. We have added the js file in index.html of angular

When user closes the payment modal window, moves away from page and comes back the modal window opens automatically (containing old values). We have used the native window to open razorpay popup and our code is like below

```
const RAZORPAY_OPTIONS:any = {
      "key": key,
      "order_id": order id generated at backend, 
      "amount": orderAmount,
    "currency": customerCurrency,
    "name": "name",
    "image": "logo",    
  
    "prefill": {
      "name": customerName,
      "email": customerEmail,
      "contact": customerPhone
  },
  
      "modal": {},
        "theme": {
          "color": "#000"
        }
  
    };
    RAZORPAY_OPTIONS['modal.ondismiss'] = this.razorpayReload.bind(this);
    RAZORPAY_OPTIONS['handler'] = this.razorPaySuccessHandler.bind(this);
    const rzp = new this.razorpayService.nativeWindow.Razorpay(RAZORPAY_OPTIONS);
    rzp.open();
  }
```